Unable to install `evals` python cli for OpenAI
Failing to install: pip install evals. For complete logs please see this gist file here.
Tools Version:

python --version: Python 3.9.6
pip --version: pip 24.2 from /Users/apple/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)

Collecting keras<2.8,>=2.7.0rc0 (from tensorflow<3.0.0,>=2.4.0->spacy-universal-sentence-encoder->evals)
  Using cached keras-2.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.3 kB)
Collecting tensorboard~=2.6 (from tensorflow<3.0.0,>=2.4.0->spacy-universal-sentence-encoder->evals)
  Using cached tensorboard-2.17.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
  Using cached tensorboard-2.17.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
  Using cached tensorboard-2.13.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.8 kB)
  Using cached tensorboard-2.11.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.9 kB)
Collecting protobuf (from google-generativeai->evals)
  Using cached protobuf-3.20.3-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl.metadata (679 bytes)
Collecting tensorboard~=2.6 (from tensorflow<3.0.0,>=2.4.0->spacy-universal-sentence-encoder->evals)
  Using cached tensorboard-2.11.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.9 kB)
  Using cached tensorboard-2.10.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.9 kB)
  Using cached tensorboard-2.10.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.9 kB)
  Using cached tensorboard-2.7.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.9 kB)
  Using cached tensorboard-2.6.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.9 kB)
Collecting tensorflow<3.0.0,>=2.4.0 (from spacy-universal-sentence-encoder->evals)
  Using cached tensorflow-2.7.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl.metadata (2.9 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow-2.7.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl.metadata (2.9 kB)
INFO: pip is still looking at multiple versions of tf-keras to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
  Using cached tensorflow-2.6.5-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow-2.6.4-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow-2.6.3-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow-2.6.2-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow-2.6.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow-2.6.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow-2.5.3-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow-2.5.2-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow-2.5.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
  Using cached tensorflow-2.5.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
Collecting SQLAlchemy<3,>=1.4 (from langchain->evals)
  Using cached SQLAlchemy-2.0.35-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl.metadata (9.6 kB)
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. See https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/backtracking for guidance. If you want to abort this run, press Ctrl + C.
  Using cached SQLAlchemy-2.0.34-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl.metadata (9.6 kB)
  Using cached SQLAlchemy-2.0.33-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl.metadata (9.6 kB)
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 105, in _run_wrapper
    status = _inner_run()
  File "/Users/apple/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 96, in _inner_run
    return self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/apple/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 67, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/Users/apple/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 379, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/Users/apple/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 95, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/Users/apple/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 546, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/Users/apple/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 457, in resolve
    raise ResolutionTooDeep(max_rounds)
pip._vendor.resolvelib.resolvers.ResolutionTooDeep: 200000

As we can see in the end of below log, we see some error. Please help me debug this, I'm new to python and tried to find the answer but couldn't figure it out after waiting to install this for like 1 hours twice. The error is like pip._vendor.resolvelib.resolvers.ResolutionTooDeep: 200000.
Please help. Thanks in advance.
Github Respository issue by me on this python library: https://github.com/openai/evals/issues/1563
Community Post on OpenAI: https://community.openai.com/t/im-not-able-to-install-evals-python-library/981186

Did you search around for the error message? What did you find that didn't work for you?

I tried to follow this guide here (as the link in above text suggests  - https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/dependency-resolution/#possible-ways-to-reduce-backtracking (its redirected from this link actually - https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/backtracking).
From there I tried this - pip install evals --no-deps
Using that command the installation is successful in 5-6 seconds but still I am getting an error as shown in this gist.

Thanks for the image removal suggestion. I just removed the image and updated with code.

Yes, with the --no-deps option, you'll have to install all the dependencies yourself. That may be a good thing (albeit a bit of extra work), since you may have to install one dependency in a specific way, which may depend on your OS. In particular, the default pytorch installation (and that of related packages) may require a different repository or some extra options when installing. You can find all the dependencies listed in the pyproject.toml file in the project's repository.

I updated my python to latest version from official python website on recommendation of @stark-jarvis, and that helped me. Thanks @stark-jarvis.

On windows 11, simply install using pip v 24.2 and command
pip install evals

OP tried this - "Failing to install: pip install evals" and "pip --version: pip 24.2 from /Users/apple/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)"

I am using macos, and linux. Thanks for trying @stark-jarvis.
